# Failing to execute Quick Import of GML files to feature class database using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, arcgis-10.6, data-interoperability

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1.

I am attempting to import GML files from the TOP10NL datasets (the historical data is only available as a package of GML files). In ArcCatalog, I selected "Dutch TOP10 GML" as the format and left the coordinate system as unknown. I selected all 14 GML files, and received the following message at the end of running the tool. The error, immediately following the message "translation was successful" and "Done import" was the message " Failed to execute (QuickImport).

I am using the Data Interoperability extension (authorized extension), and I have turned off background processing (as it is buggy for me).

[[image: Image of results messages[1]]

So, the tool ran in entirety, but then failed. I'm not sure how to best address this, and I am really in need of this dataset.I don't know if it has anything to do with the size of the files or the number of features, I suspect this may be the case but I also would prefer to have all the files in one FC database. (14 files, all around 300 MB, total features 2648770).

I attempted processing one GML file on its own. I also realized that the GML files are all displaying in ArcCatalog as feature datasets. Each of the TOP10 GML files appears to contain the same feature classes (33 in total per feature dataset, or GML file in this case). However, when I processed one of the GML files into a geodatabase, only two of the feature classes from the GML file are present in the GDB. It said the tool was successful, but a warning within the messages reads:

> xfmap- Can't determine axis order from coordinate system or settings. Using assumed axis order of 1,2.

I'm not sure how to follow up here; does anyone have specific experience with Dutch TOP10 NL files?

[image: GML versus GBD results]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fairly likely that it (the Interoperability Extension) can't find the right schema to use with the data. I just tried reading a file and that's what happened to me.

Look in the log for a line such as:

> 2019-07-05 12:14:05|   0.2|  0.0|INFORM| - No
>   explicit XML Schema specified (through the XSD_DOC keyword) nor an
>   xsi:schemaLocation or xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation were found in
>   dataset 'C:\Users\imark\Documents\Black Hole\top10nl-source.gml',
>   determining schema files from the dataset XML namespace
>   declarations...

So... if your file is called top10nl-data.gml, copy the schema file locally and call it top10nl-data.xsd - then the extension will use the local copy of the schema and read the data.

If you don't have a copy of the schema, it's likely to be installed in the extension somewhere. Look for xml\schemas\top10 in its install directory.

Note: Yes, the GML files will display in ArcCatalog as feature datasets, because of the Interoperability extension. In fact any supported format should. The problem here is that .gml is an ambiguous extension that could apply to any GML format, so it's probably getting interpreted as plain GML.

Comment: Hi @Mark Ireland I am not sure I follow your suggestion. There is a schema, but I am getting the message "A <schemaLocation> in the uri-map is overriding the namespace '[.....]', etc." Could this also be an issue? I have XML and XSD files in the dataset of gml files under the product information folder within the download set.